# Porque meu montante está dando "inf"? Python

Tags: python, while, ciclo-infinito

Fala pessoal!

Estou resolvendo um exercício, e o meu resultado comparado ao da resposta do livro (que estão bem parecidos) não dá certo. O meu resultado da uma resposta Infinita, e o do livro não, da os 24 meses necessários. A dúvida é: o que tem de errado no meu código? O que está diferente do livro?

OBS: Pessoal, primeira postagem, não sabia que era melhor mandar os códigos digitados do que imagem. Então segue abaixo os códigos digitados.

Segue também, o enunciado:

> Escreva um programa que pergunte o valor inicial de uma dívida e o juros mensal. Pergunte também o valor mensal que será pago. Imprima o número de meses para que a dívida seja paga, o total pago e o total de juros pago.

MEU CÓDIGO:

```
juros = float(input("Qual a % de juros mensais? "))
valor_mensal = float(input("Digite o valor mensal a ser pago: R$ "))
mes = 1
if divida * (juros / 100) > valor_mensal:
    print("Você nunca irá pagar a dívida, pois os juros são superiores ao valor mensal.")
else:
    montante = divida
    juros_pago = 0
    while montante > valor_mensal:
        juros = montante * juros / 100
        montante = montante + juros - valor_mensal
        juros_pago = juros_pago + juros
        print(f"No mês {mes}, o montante está em R$ {montante:.2f}.")
        mes = mes + 1
    print(f"No total, levou-se {mes - 1} meses para pagar a dívida.")
    print(f"O total pago foi de R$ {divida + juros_pago:.2f}")
    print(f"O total de juros pago foi de R$ {juros_pago:.2f}")
```

[Meu resultado, dando infinito como mencionado acima.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7d8u.png)

---

CÓDIGO DO LIVRO (a se comparar com o meu):

```
taxa = float(input("Juros (Ex.: 3 para 3%): "))
pagamento = float(input("Pagamento mensal:"))
mês = 1
if dívida * (taxa/100) > pagamento:
    print("Sua dívida não será paga nunca, pois os juros são superiores ao pagamento mensal.")
else:
    saldo = dívida
    juros_pago = 0
    while saldo > pagamento:
        juros = saldo * taxa / 100
        saldo = saldo + juros - pagamento
        juros_pago = juros_pago + juros
        print(f"Saldo da dívida no mês {mês} é de R${saldo:6.2f}.")
        mês = mês + 1
    print(f"Para pagar uma dívida de R${dívida:8.2f}, a {taxa:5.2f} % de juros,")
    print(f"você precisará de {mês - 1} meses, pagando um total de R${juros_pago:8.2f} de juros.")
    print(f"No último mês, você teria um saldo residual de R${saldo:8.2f} a pagar.")
```

[Resultado do livro, dando 24 meses corretamente.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAD83.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Obrigada pela dica! Já ajustei a postagem e a deixei bem mais completa.

Answer (score -2):

Não soa estranho para você que o mês está em 138717? Provavelmente, seu *while* está sem condição de parada. Considere:

```
import sys
sys.float_info
```

> sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308)

```
def juros(C, i, n):
    return C * (1 + i) ** n

juros(10000, 0.01, 70000)
```

> 3.134474817003861e+306

Conforme o valor (C) e a taxa (i), facilmente você chega ao valor máximo permitido. Por exemplo:

```
juros(10000, 0.01, 70000) ** 2
```

Retorna

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square after removing the cwd from sys.path.

> array([inf])

Não é possível saber o porquê da falta de condição de parada sem que o código completo seja disponibilizado.

Comment: Olá!! Obrigada pela dica. Ajustei a postagem com os códigos certinho e acho que agora da pra entender melhor. De fato eu não queria que desse um número de meses infinito como esse, queria que desse apenas 24 meses rsrs